# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 exception

Tags: ssms-2014

I open my SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and try to open any table from my databases, I got this message.

[image: ssms2014Exception]

When I follow the path below I don't have a folder called `Microsoft\AppEnv\10.0\ActivityLog.xml`.

Comment: Try this method to read the log=>https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2506/identify-location-of-the-sql-server-error-log-file/

Comment: doesn't help sorry